# grub recovery mode: etc/resolv.conf: no such file or directory

Tags: boot, networking, grub2

Ive installed ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop a few months ago and suddenly I can t get past the splash screen.

[Where I m stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJv7v.jpg)

(i see the red dots gradually becoming white and vice-verca, so something is happening, but I can t get past this screen)

I thus decided to boot in recovery mode to update and upgrade all my packages. But once I get there I have no internet access (with or without ethernet cable). This is what I get when trying to enable networking:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHLxH.jpg

Could someone explain me how to have internet access so I can hopefully be able to solve my other issue in order to be able to log in again on my machine?

Comment: during early bootup press the arrow keys so you can get into the grub menu. Press "e" to edit the top "ubuntu" entry. Remove "splash" in the kernel line. Press ctrl-x. It will hopefully show you the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me... 
Enabling network from recovery gave me this same error. 
From the root terminal in recovery mode, I ran  the command "sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf" 
I answered yes to the first prompt but didn't restart after the second prompt. 
After going back to the root terminal I was able to resolve Google.com when I tried to ping it. Then I could use apt to install the packages I needed.